# Join with trigger in siddhi

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi

I have a question. I am using DAS 3.0.1.

Trazablack is a postgres table.

I cant make a join with the event Trazafiltrada, it's was create with the next code:

```
define trigger FiveMinTriggerStream at every 5 min;

from FiveMinTriggerStream join Trazablack as t
select t.sensorValue as sensorValue
insert into TrazaFiltrada;
```

But, I want make a join with of other event different, I'm using the next code:

```
from sensorStream JOIN TrazaFiltrada
on sensorStream.sensorValue==TrazaFiltrada.sensorValue
select sensorStream.meta_timestamp, sensorStream.meta_sensorName,
       sensorStream.correlation_longitude, sensorStream.correlation_latitude, sensorStream.sensorValue as valor1, TrazaFiltrada.sensorValue as valor2
insert into StreamPaso;

Trazablack           TrazaFiltrada         sensorStream
----------           -------------         -------------
156                   156                   156
170                   170 
85                    85
```

My problem is that this query is null. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, is important read the documentation for the next time.

WSO2 say:

1. Join takes two streams as the input
2. **Each stream must have an associated window**
3. It generates the output events composed of one event from each stream
4. With “on ” Siddhi joins only the events that matches the condition
5. With “within ”, Siddhi joins only the events that are within that time of each other